# Search text file and save result to another text file

Tags: python, file, search, text

I am pretty new to python and have only very limited programming skills with it. I hope you can help me here.

I have a large text file and I'm searching it for a specific word. Every line with this word needs to be stored to another txt file.

I can search the file and print the result in the console but not to a different file. How can I manage that?

```
f = open("/tmp/LostShots/LostShots.txt", "r")

searchlines = f.readlines()
f.close()
for i, line in enumerate(searchlines):
    if "Lost" in line: 
        for l in searchlines[i:i+3]: print l,
        print

f.close()
```

Thx
Jan

Comment: why not use grep? : $grep word file > newFile

Comment: Since you can obviously write code for opening and reading a file, you will also be able to open a file for writing and writing data inside it. If not: every Python tutorial tells you.

Comment: `with open('/tmp/LostShosts/LostShots.txt') as f, open('/tmp/found.txt') as f2: f2.writelines(line for line in f if 'Lost' in line)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `with` context manager, do not use [readlines()](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#file.readlines) since it will read the whole contents of a file into a list. Instead iterate over [file object](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#file-objects) line by line and see if a specific word is there; if yes - write to the output file:

```
with open("/tmp/LostShots/LostShots.txt", "r") as input_file, \ 
     open('results.txt', 'w') as output_file:

    for line in input_file:
        if "Lost" in line:
            output_file.write(line)
```

Note that for python < 2.7, you cannot have multiple items in `with`:

```
with open("/tmp/LostShots/LostShots.txt", "r") as input_file:
    with open('results.txt', 'w') as output_file:

        for line in input_file:
            if "Lost" in line:
                output_file.write(line)
```

Comment: Your code also matches "blaLostbla", but the OP asked for lines that contain the **word** "Lost" not the **string** "Lost".

Comment: @ErikAllik may be you are right. Depends on what the OP really meant and what kind of data is there. Thanks.

Comment: Anyway, don't think this deserves -1.

Comment: My plan was to remove the downvote once it actually matches **words** not substrings :P because I'm quite sure the OP didn't mean substrings... it wouldn't be very meaningful with human readable text.

Comment: Let's wait when the OP will clarify things: may be comment or accept the answer.

Comment: Hi, in line       with open("/tmp/LostShots/LostShots.txt", "r") as input_file, \           I got an error saying "SyntaxError: unexpected character after line continuation character". What exactly is here causing it? I already tried to delete the "," and "\" but thats not working. There specific lines with Lost in it, so its ok when its looking for the string Lost.

Comment: @user2834508 take a look at the updated answer, hope that helps.

Comment: FTR, "unexpected character after line continuation character" is what you get if you put something, even a space, after `\` in a line.

Comment: @user2834508: please put "blaLost" in your input file and see if the output is still what you need.

Answer (score 1):

To correctly match words in general, you need regular expressions; a simple `word in line` check also matches `blablaLostblabla` which I assume you don't want:

```
import re

with open("/tmp/LostShots/LostShots.txt", "r") as input_file, \ 
        open('results.txt', 'w') as output_file:

    output_file.writelines(line for line in input_file
                           if re.match(r'.*\bLost\b', line)
```

or you can use a more wordy

```
    for line in input_file:
        if re.match(r'.*\bLost\b', line)):
            output_file.write(line)
```

As a side note, you should be using `os.path.join` to make paths; also, for working with temporary files in a cross-platform manner, see the functions in the `tempfile` module.